# How to select all where there is no match SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a bunch of records of providers and their phone numbers from 2 different databases and I'm trying to find those providers where the phone number from one database (Phone2) does not match any of the ones from the other (Phone1). The phone number from database 2 (Phone2) is always the same per ID. Database 1 (Phone1) can have multiple phone numbers

| ID | PHONE1 | PHONE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5126078099 | 5129082933 |
| 1 | 5129082933 | 5129082933 |
| 2 | 9506079090 | 9504057890 |
| 2 | 9823939393 | 9504057890 |
| 3 | 7555769000 | 7552939302 |
| 3 | 7552939302 | 7552939302 |

In this case only provider with ID 2 should be on my report since none of the phone numbers match.  How can I get this?

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM Table a
WHERE a.PHONE2 NOT IN (SELECT b.PHONE1 FROM Table b WHERE a.ID = b.ID)
```

But this didn't work

Comment: Why didn't your solution work? https://dbfiddle.uk/JqsePIzV

Comment: Look at Set based operations like MINUS / Except to achieve this simply.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM [Table] a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Table] b
    WHERE b.ID = a.ID AND b.Phone1 = a.Phone2
)
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/XeoI8MoL

Answer (score 1):

Your query has the right idea but the `NOT IN` subquery is returning any non-matching number - even if there's a matching one for the same ID in another record.

To solve this, you should ensure that an ID appears only when none of the its "PHONE1" numbers match its "PHONE2" number. Using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`, here is a query that should match your desired functionality:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.PHONE2
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN Table b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.PHONE2 = b.PHONE1
GROUP BY a.ID, a.PHONE2
HAVING COUNT(b.PHONE1) = 0;
```

This will join the table on itself based on matching IDs, then groups the results and filters it, retaining only those IDs which there are no corresponding matches between the "PHONE1" and "PHONE2" values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` and check for `null` values to identify not-matched ones

```
SELECT b.id, b.phone2
FROM `Table` a
RIGHT JOIN `Table` b
ON a.phone1 = b.phone2
WHERE a.phone1 IS NULL
GROUP BY b.id;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce38ec/7)

Comment: You're using MySQL syntax for a SQL Server question - please correct it.

Comment: No, thats your job if you are providing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider set based operations.  These allow one to subtract sets of data from eachter.  Data set B matches are removed from Set A leaving you with ones from set A that didn't exactly match in set b.

Set based operations are usally efficient and conceptually easy to understand.  If data exists in set A and we subtract data from set B. The result is those things in Set A not found in Set B.

Look up set based operations using union, except, intersect etc.

[More on MSSQL set based operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

and then a deeper dive into [set theory](https://www.sqlshack.com/mathematics-sql-server-fast-introduction-set-theory/)

example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/lZfJK2Sq

```
SELECT ID, Phone2
FROM test a

EXCEPT -- Some RDBMS use MINUS intead. but it's the same thing

SELECT ID, phone1 
FROM test b
```

Resulting in

```
ID  Phone2
2   9504057890
```

Conceptually it's:

```
D   PHONE2
1   5129082933
2   9504057890
3   7552939302
```

MINUS

```
D   PHONE1
1   5126078099
1   5129082933  --Matches in 1set set so gets excluded
2   9506079090
2   9823939393
3   7555769000
3   7552939302  -- Matches in 1set set so gets excluded
```

Resulting in:

```
2   9504057890
```